# wpf C# update dependency property from another dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am kind of new to WPF, I have the following scenario. I want to display a value of a 'Pressure Regulator' in the WPF Label, however, the pressure regulator is not necesserily connected. If it is, I display its value, if it's not I'd like to display e.g., "N/A" string.
To model this scenario I created a class 'OutputValues'  with two Dependency Properties - PressureRegulatorValue (double type) and HasPressureRegualator (bool type):

```
public class OutputValues : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       // ... some stuff
public bool HasPressureRegulator
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasPressureRegulatorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasPressureRegulatorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HasPressureRegulator.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasPressureRegulatorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasPressureRegulator", typeof(bool), typeof(OutputValues), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OutputValues.OnHasPressureRegulatorChanged)));

private static void OnHasPressureRegulatorChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // not sure whether to put any code here
    }

public double PressureRegulatorValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PressureRegulatorValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressureRegulatorValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PressureRegulatorValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressureRegulatorValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PressureRegulatorValue", typeof(double), typeof(OutputValues), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
// ... some more stuff
}
```

Now I want to bind the Label which is in my GUI (it is part of UserControl called OutputValuesViewer) to an instance of this class. When I bind Label to a data source, the data source should be a dependency property I guess, so in **OutputValuesViewer** UserControl I created a DP:

```
    public OutputValues OutputValues
    {
        get { return (OutputValues)GetValue(OutputValuesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutputValuesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for OutputValues.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OutputValues", typeof(OutputValues), typeof(OutputValuesViewer));
```

I initialize this property in the constructor of **OutputValuesViewer**:

```
    public OutputValuesViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.OutputValues = new OutputValues();
    }
```

Finally my XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OperationDescriptionEditor.OutputValuesViewer"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns:conversion="clr-namespace:OperationDescriptionEditor">
<!-- Unimportant stuff is left out -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btvc" />
    <conversion:OutputValuesToPressureRegulatorStringConverter x:Key="ovtprsc" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<!-- More stuff -->
<Label Content="{Binding Path=OutputValues, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ovtprsc}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="lblPressureRegulatorValue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="9" />
```

So I bind the label to the OutputValues DP and I implemented a converter which creates the resulting string based on if HasPressureRegulator is true or not and also based on PressureRegulatorValue. I have a sort of a two-level DP. OutputValues is a DP and since it returns an instance of OutputValues class, I can access its two other DPs so:
OutputValues.HasPressureRegulator
OutputValues.PressureRegulatorValue

Now I would expect that if OutputValues.HasPressureRegulator changes, Label would automatically refresh itself. This does not happen though. I tried adding PropertyValueChanged callback to both:
OutputValues.HasPressureRegulator - the callback fires
OutputValues - the callback does not fire
So I'm guessing that Label does not know that it should refresh itself, because OutputValues property (which Label is bound to) does not inform it about a change.
The question is how should HasPressureRegulator DP inform its "parent" OutputValues DP that its value has changed?

As you can see from the code, I tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on OutputValues class, but that did not work.

Much thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you think the DependencyObject is supposed to do. Ordinarily you would add DPs to a UserControl (say), although even in that case this code wouldn't work because bindings (specifically, your binding to OutputValues) are done relative to the DataContext, so you would have to update that binding and point it to the UserControl itself. I think you need to take a step back and explain exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My OutputValues class is not a UserControl or other GUI-related control. So in order for it to contain DPs, it has to inherit from DependencyObject class so that it can call GetValue and SetValue methods.

The OutputValuesViewer class (which is a UserControl) then contains an OutputValues DP (whose type is OutputValues). Since the Label is part of OutputValuesViewer I set DataContext to 'this'  using XAML, as the data source is part of that OutputValuesViewer UserControl.

Comment: To solve your specific issue, you could use a `IMultiValueConverter` and bind it to both `HasPressureRegulator` and `PressureRegulatorValue` (using a `MultiBinding`). This way, your value will be refreshed when either of the properties is updated.

Comment: @user6056425 ok, but just so you know in my humble opinion you're using DP's in a way in which they really aren't used any more, that particular usage has been pretty much replaced by the MVVM flavour of data binding. In fact I think it's fair to say that the overwhelming majority of DP usage these days is in the form of user control properties and attached dependency properties, both of which are UI-specific. If it's change notification you're after then the usual mechanism for that is INPC.

Comment: @KooKiz - thx for the advice, I'll take a  look at IMultiValueConverter .

Comment: @MarkFeldman - I'm certainly not insisting that my approach is ideal, therefore I would appreciate any advice which would solve my issue. As you can see from the source code I tried to implement INPC on OutputValues class, however, that did not work. I added a code which should fire PropertyChanged event if any of the two DPs change their value (for that I added property changed callbacks to them). However, even when I was stepping through the debugger I noticed that the PropertyChanged events won't be fired from OutputValues class, because PropertyChanged was null.

Comment: @VladimírGregor certainly happy to post code showing how I would normally implement this myself, but I have to ask first how you're binding those DPs to the other data in your application? Where do the values for HasPressureRegulator and PressureRegulatorValue ultimately come from?

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. All you actually need is a view model property of type double (i.e. a view model class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged with a PressureRegulatorValue of type double, which would not be a dependency property). In case the regulator is not connected, the property value would be `double.NaN`. Then you would write a binding converter that converts the property value to an appropriate string.

Comment: @MarkFeldman - The values come from an XML file. The application we're creating is going to be an editor/visualizer of XML file which contains a description of an operation. That XML description will then be used as an input file for another application.

Comment: @Clemens - this is a good advice, thank you. However I wanted to keep my description short therefore I included only two DPs in my post. In reality the OutputValues class has more DPs which altogether influence how the resulting string (of the Label) is created. To be more exact, the value of the pressure regulator (if pressure regulator is present - determined by HasPressureRegulator DP), can be specified directly by a value (PressureRegulatorValue DP) or by a reference to a parameter which is then read from the data base (PressureRegulatorParamRef DP whose type is string).